# Lost files only appear in chkdsk statistics

Tags: filesystems, sd-card, chkdsk

I'm expreriencing a strange problem with an external SD card which has been mistakenly pulled out from the pc reader. About half of the files seem to have been lost because they do not appear in the explorer and neither in the properties. The strange thing is that chkdisk doesn't report any problem and it counts the right number of files.
Is there a way I can recover those? I'm running on windows 8 but have access to an ubuntu machine (in case there was some trick with it).

Thanks

Comment: What `chkdsk` command line are you using to check the device?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg plain chkdsk, no options (cd d: -> chkdsk)

Comment: Try it with `/B` if the drive is NTFS formatted, otherwise use `/R`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg using linux I found an hidden folder called FOUND.000 which contained all the missing files with extension .CHK, thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Awesome :) It would be great if you could post an answer and accept it as the correct solution once that is possible. This might help future visitors. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that those files really existed in a hidden folder named FOUND.000. The folder was visible in ubuntu and it can be probably shown (I haven't tried) on windows 8 by viewing hidden system files.